# How to avoid truncating my CSV output in a Python for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a large folder of CSV files and I need to go into each one and add a new column with a new field.

My code seems to only return the number of rows that are in the first file. All my output files now only have 67 rows. I'm thinking this is because the first CSV had 67 rows and then my code just stuck to that? Any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
import glob, os

files = glob.glob('path/*.csv')

for file in files: # loop through each file
    df['client'] = 'newContent' 
    df.to_csv(file)
```

Comment: Where did `df` get created? Are you maybe just writing the same dataframe to every filename?

Comment: You need to read the files before modifying and rewriting them!  Something like `df = pd.read_csv(file)` as the first line in your looping  block.

Comment: where `df = pd.read_csv(file)` ? And it has to be inside `for`-loop.

Comment: @furas Do you read comments before adding your own?  You said the same thing I said.

Comment: @RufusVS I have a feeling I didn't see your comment but funny is I upvoted it :)

Comment: Thank you to all of you! This helped out a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my comment wasn't clear enough, here's the modified program:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob, os

files = glob.glob('path/*.csv')

for file in files: # loop through each file
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df['client'] = 'newContent' 
    df.to_csv(file)
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you!!

Comment: I hope you back up your files before you run any kind of program like this.   If you like this answer, you can mark it as accepted answer.